# How to add text to "edit box" control in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, winapi, editing

I want to add some text on a dialog in VS 2005. I have installed Microsoft SDK on my system.

The text which I want to add is very big, it runs upto 4 pages.

So I decided to add edit control with scrollbar, which I am not able to do.

I tried adding through string table, but formatting was not maintained.

Plz let me know, how to show a formatted text upto 4 pages on a dialog.

My application is non MFC application.

Thanks in advance

Vinayaka Karjigi

Answer (score 2):

The edit control has a hard limit of 65k worth of text. You may be running into that. Try a rich edit control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the [MultiLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370524%28VS.85%29.aspx) attribute of your edit control?

Comment: I have tried muklti line.
But text is more, so i wanted to know how to add that 4 page text to the edit box?

Comment: I see, sorry pal, can't really help you on this. Hope some others can. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually adding "\r\n" for next line or "\t" for tab in the string buffer. That may do the trick.

**Update**: Say you want to break the text in two lines TCHAR szEditBoxBuffer[] = TEXT("Hello\r\nWorld"); may do the trick. For tabs TCHAR szEditBoxBuffer[] = TEXT("Hello\tWorld"); This is tedious but this is what i could think of.